# Change default switch statement auto-complete order

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

Is there an option in the Eclipse workspace properties to change the order that the "incomplete-switch" warning auto-populates cases within the switch statement? For example, if I have an enum:

```
enum TraversalType{
    PREORDER,
    INORDER,
    POSTORDER;
}
```

When you use this and have the switch statement warning auto complete the cases within the body of the switch, it seems to always order alphabetically. Is there an option to change this and use the ordering, like in this example, to look like:

```
switch(TraversalType pType){
    case PREORDER:
        break;
    case INORDER:
        break;
    case POSTORDER:
        break;
}
```

every time, instead of just after manually entering the cases?

Comment: Why is this -1'd?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the ordering of case statements in the Eclipse auto complete feature of "add missing case statements". However you can sort the enum members alphabetically to match the order of the auto inserted switch cases.